# continuation in common lisp by macros -- regarding an implemetation in OnLisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, continuations, continuation-passing, on-lisp

In [*On Lisp*](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.pdf), p. 267, Paul Graham provides an implementation of continuation passing macros:

```
(setq *cont* #'identity)

(defmacro =lambda (parms &body body)
  `#'(lambda (*cont* ,@parms) ,@body))

(defmacro =defun (name parms &body body)
  (let ((f (intern (concatenate 'string
                "=" (symbol-name name)))))
    `(progn
       (defmacro ,name ,parms
     `(,',f *cont* ,,@parms))
       (defun ,f (*cont* ,@parms) ,@body))))

(defmacro =bind (parms expr &body body)
  `(let ((*cont* #'(lambda ,parms ,@body))) ,expr))

(defmacro =values (&rest retvals)
  `(funcall *cont* ,@retvals))
```

The following code to traverse a tree `t2` for each leaf of a tree `t1`, uses this implementation, and I am wondering what happens when `restart` is called, especially after when the leaf of `t1` changed from `A` (the first element) to `B` (the second element).  When `restart` is called, it simply pops a lambda function from `*saved*`, and that lambda function calls `dft-node` with `(cdr tree)` again.
But this call is made *outside* the scope of the outermost `=bind`, and `=bind` was responsible for binding `*cont*`.  How is the binding of `*cont*` introduced by the outer `=bind` still in scope, then?

```
(setq *saved* nil)

(=defun dft-node (tree)
    (cond ((null tree) (restart))
          ((atom tree) (=values tree))
          (t (push #'(lambda () (dft-node (cdr tree))) *saved*)
             (dft-node (car tree)))))

(=defun restart ()
    (if *saved*
        (funcall (pop *saved*))
      (=values 'done)))

(setq t1 '(a (b (d h)) (c e (f i) g))
      t2 '(1 (2 (3 6 7) 4 5)))

(=bind (node1) (dft-node t1)
  (if (eq node1 'done)
      'done
    (=bind (node2) (dft-node t2)
      (list node1 node2))))
```

The last form expands to

```
(let ((*cont* (lambda (node1)
                (if (eq node1 'done)
                    'done
                    (let ((*cont* (lambda (node2)
                                    (list node1 node2))))
                      (dft-node t2))
  (dft-node t1))))))
```

This produces `(a 1)`.  According to Graham, subsequent calls to `restart` should produce `(a 2)`, and so on, up to `(a 5)`, and then subsequent calls should produce `(b 1)`, `(b 2)`, and so on, until finally `(g 5)`:

```
> (let ((node1 (dft-node t1)))
    (if (eq? node1 ’done)
        ’done
        (list node1 (dft-node t2))))
(A 1)
> (restart)
(A 2)
…
> (restart)
(B 1)
```

After `(a 1)`, the binding of `*cont*` established by `let` should no longer be in place.  How do subsequent calls to `restart` these values? Is the scope of `let` still applied to a separate call to `restart`? What is going on here?

Comment: Your interpretation that this doesn't make much sense is absolutely right.  Graham notes later on that this **doesn't work** if \*cont* is declared as a special (i.e., dynamically scoped) variable;  \*cont* needs to be lexically scoped.  However, there are no lexically scoped global variables in Common Lisp, and his assumption that `(setq *cont* …)` makes one is just *wrong*.  I've updated my answer to reflect this, and I now better understand your question.

Comment: **However, there are no lexically scoped global variables in Common Lisp** This part is true.  Common Lisp doesn't have global lexical variables.  **and his assumption that (setq \*cont* …) makes one is just wrong.**  I was incorrect about this.  *On Lisp* slightly predates the specification of Common Lisp, so Graham didn't have a the ANSI Common Lisp specification to work against.  The assumption doesn't hold for Common Lisp, but that does not mean that Graham was incorrect in making that assumption in *On Lisp*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *On Lisp* slightly predates Common Lisp, so there are some incompatibilities

*On Lisp* was written before Common Lisp had actually been solidified as a language, so there are some incompatibilities between the code that appears in *On Lisp* and Common Lisp. The [CLiki entry on *On Lisp*](http://www.cliki.net/on%20lisp) notes that these continuation passing macros are actually one of the places where there's an incompatibility (emphasis added):

> When defining continuation-passing macros (p. 267) Paul Graham seems
>   to be assuming that *cont* global variable has lexical scope. This
>   contradicts Common Lisp standard. **With present day Common Lisp
>   implementations, the aforementioned macros just don't work. Also, this
>   issue can be very confusing for newcomers.** Suggested solutions for
>   fixing the macros are (note that #'values is used instead of
>    #'identity - according to Paul Graham's Errata):
>
> - emulate lexically scoped global variable *cont* using symbol-macro that can be shadowed by let or lambda:
>     (defvar *actual-cont* #'values)
>     (define-symbol-macro *cont* *actual-cont*)
> - just omit (setq *cont* #'identity) and call "top-level" continuation-passing function as (=somefunc #'values ...)
> - …

That's a pretty short description of the problem, and it's worth looking into a bit more, to help any newcomers who come across it in the future.  It may also be helpful to see other discussions of this same issue, including:

- [Page 268 of <On Lisp>...](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/d4KfGp9R7RE/iewBHqj5o0QJ) A comp.lang.lisp thread from 2006 in which a user asks about the difference between **(setq *cont* …)** and **(defvar *cont* …)**.  In this thread, people note that *On Lisp* predates ANSI Common Lisp.

### What's actually happening?

Since **(=bind …)** expands to **(let ((*cont* …)) …)**, you're absolutely right in that, if ***cont*** is a special variable (i.e., with dynamic extent), then once you're outside of that **let**, the original binding of ***cont***, which is **identity** is what should be in place for calls to restarts.  If ***cont*** is declared special, then you get the following behavior:

```
CONTINUATIONS> (=bind (node1) (dft-node '(a (b (d h)) (c e (f i) g)))
                 (if (eq node1 'done)
                     'done
                     (=bind (node2) (dft-node '(1 (2 (3 6 7) 4 5)))
                       (list node1 node2))))
(A 1)
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
2
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
3
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
6
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
7
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
4
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
5
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
B
CONTINUATIONS> (restart)
D
```

This makes sense, because after getting (a 1), ***saved*** contains two functions.  The first is one that will continue traversing the numeric tree on the next branch, and the ***cont*** that will be called is the global one, **#'identity**, since we're now outside of the **=bind** form.  That's why we get 2, 3, … as results.  The second function in ***saved*** at this point is the one that will continue traversing the alphabetic tree at B.

The reason that we don't get a bunch of lists (a 1), (a 2), …, (b 1), etc., above is that we (reasonably) assumed that ***cont*** is special, i.e., dynamically bound.  It turns out that Graham intends for ***cont*** *not* to be special;  he wants it to be a global lexical. From [*On Lisp*](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.pdf), page 268:

> It is by manipulating `*cont*` that we will get the effect of
>   continuations. Although `*cont*` has a global value, this will rarely be
>   the one used: `*cont*` will nearly always be a parameter, captured by
>   `=values` and the macros deﬁned by
>   `=defun`. Within the body of `add1`, for example, `*cont*` is a parameter and not the global variable. This distinction is important because these
>   macros wouldn’t work if `*cont*` were not a local variable. That’s why
>   `*cont*` is given its initial value in a `setq` instead of a `defvar`: the latter would also proclaim it to be special.

*On Lisp* slightly predates Common Lisp, so this wasn't necessarily incorrect at the time of writing, but Common Lisp doesn't actually have global lexical variables, so it's not the case that using **(setq *cont* …)** at the top-level will necessarily create a global lexical variable.  In Common Lisp, the exact results are unspecified.  Some implementations will treat it like a global lexical, others will assume that you meant **defparameter** or **defvar**, and you'll end up with a global *special* variable.  As Graham notes, that won't work.  It sounds like you've got an implementation that does the latter, so things don't work.

Some implementations will actually complain about his code.  SBCL, for instance, rightly complains at `(setq *cont* …)`, printing "warning: undefined variable: CONTINUATIONS::*CONT*", and issues a style warning when ***cont*** is used that it is "using the lexical binding of the symbol (CONTINUATIONS::*CONT*), not the dynamic binding, even though the name follows the usual naming convention (names like *FOO*) for special variables."

### What's supposed to happen?

To understand how this is *supposed* to work, it's probably easier to look at a simpler implementation that doesn't have all the plumbing that's in the *On Lisp* version:

```
(defparameter *restarts* '())

(defun do-restart ()
  (if (endp *restarts*) nil
      (funcall (pop *restarts*))))

(defun traverse-tree (k tree)
  (cond
    ((null tree) (do-restart))
    ((atom tree) (funcall k tree))
    (t (push (lambda () (traverse-tree k (cdr tree))) *restarts*)
       (traverse-tree k (car tree)))))
```

Here we don't hide any of the continuation passing mechanism or the ***restarts*** list.  With this, we get this behavior:

```
CL-USER> (traverse-tree 'identity '((1 2) (3 4)))
1
CL-USER> (do-restart)
2
CL-USER> (do-restart)
3
CL-USER> (do-restart)
4
CL-USER> (do-restart)
NIL
```

We can recreate the multiple-list traversal one, too, and I think we get the results that you were expecting:

```
CL-USER> (let ((k (lambda (num)
                    (traverse-tree (lambda (alpha)
                                     (list num alpha))
                                   '(a (b) c)))))
           (traverse-tree k '((1 2) 3)))
(1 A)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(1 B)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(1 C)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(2 A)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(2 B)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(2 C)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(3 A)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(3 B)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
(3 C)
CL-USER> (do-restart)
NIL
```

The difference here is that there are no references to ***cont*** that change meaning once we leave the scope of the **let** that bound the continuation for us.

In my opinion, a better implementation would simply use a normal lexical a variable to store the continuation (sort of like **k** above, but probably with a name produced by **gensym**), and would just require that "calls to continuation passing functions must ultimately be wrapped in a **=bind** that defines the outermost continuation.

Comment: There are not many implementations which treat `(setq var ...)` as doing a special declaration for a new variable. `CMUCL` (and Scieneer CL) is known for this. But that can be switched off. See `ext:*top-level-auto-declare*`. I would always turn that off.
Generally there is a lot of undefined and stuff in CL, but real implementations make a choice: TCO yes/no, Conditions as CLOS, Streams as CLOS, SETQ undefined variable as special or not, default packages, ...

Comment: @RainerJoswig Certainly.  If more implementations made `(setq *cont* …)` at the top level do the special declaration, then Graham might not have ended up with a working example.  If fewer did, then the OP might not have ended up with a disconnect between the code in a book and the results in the REPL.  What I find frustrating in this is not necessarily the use of unspecified behavior, but the use of unspecified behavior where it's *so easily avoidable*.

Comment: I have nothing against creating 'standards' by convention. Common Lisp has way too much undefined behavior in the standard. Implementors should refrain from exploiting this and should provide a robust system with less surprises. I'd either avoid or patch implementations which provide these surprise.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I agree about standards by convention.  That's why things like the [CDR - Common Lisp Document Repository](http://cdr.eurolisp.org/) are great.  The problem here is that current implementations do different things with top level assignments to undeclared variables, and Graham is (i) assuming that they all do the same thing (no note that "some implementations will do something different"), and (ii) abusing conventions that do exist by using the  `*...*` notation for a global lexical, and (iii) doing (i) and (ii) this when it's easy to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Note that `On Lisp` was published before the ANSI standard. An alternative to requiring the continuation forms to be called within an `=bind` is to use `deflex` or a symbol macro to portably implement the current semantics.

Comment: @m-n Oh, that is a good point.  I think I'd mentally conflated his *ANSI Common Lisp* and *On Lisp*.  That does probably excuse this incompatibility.  Some sites mention *On Lisp* as a Common Lisp book, but that's clearly not the case;  Common Lisp wasn't around just yet.  The CLiki page about On Lisp calls it a Common Lisp book, but explicitly calls out the issue with these continuation passing macros!  I'm going to tone down some of my (not entirely mertited) criticism.

Comment: Hi, I still cannot understand what is happening if Graham's assumption is correct.

Comment: And 1 more confusion when Graham said "=bind, is intended to be used in the same way as multiple-value-bind. It takes a list of parameters, an expression, and a body of code: the parameters are bound to the values returned by the expression, and the code body is evaluated with those bindings."; I cannot see the binding directly from the macro definition itself. Does this only happens when =values come in?

Comment: @user1461328 About your first comment:  do you mean the assumption about the that **\*cont\*** will not be a special variable because it is assigned with **setq** rather that declared with **defvar**?

Comment: @user1461328 The implementation of `=bind` would expand code like `(=bind (a b c) expr body...)` into `(let ((*cont* #'(lambda (a b c) body...))) expr)`.  The intent is that \*cont\* will eventually be called with three values, and because the parameter list of `*cont*` is `(a b c)`, those three values will be bound to `a`, `b`, and `c`, and then the `body` will be evaluated in the scope of those bindings.  So `(=bind (a b c) expr body)` behaves very much like `(multiple-value-bind (a b c) expr body)`.  You're right, though, that if there are mutiple variables, then the expr should

Comment: @user1461328 (eventually) end with `(=values ...)`.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor for the first part, I just want to know what Graham expected when he wrote the book, especially when the result change from (A 5) to (B 1). I just wonder at this moment if the *cont* is the lambda function created by the first =bind or by the second if his assumption was correct