# regarding continuation in OnLisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, on-lisp

I am still interested in the question which has been answered.

[continuation in common lisp by macros — regarding an implemetation in OnLisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721676/continuation-in-common-lisp-by-macros-regarding-an-implemetation-in-onlisp)

What will happen if Paul Graham's assumption is correct especially when change from (A 5) to (B 1)? What is *cont* bound to here?

And one more confusion when the text says

> =bind, is intended to be used in the same way as multiple-value-bind. It takes a list of parameters, an expression, and a body of code: the parameters are bound to the values returned by the expression, and the code body is evaluated with those bindings.

I cannot see the binding directly from the macro definition of =bind which looks like

```
 (defmacro =bind (parms expr &body body)
  `(let ((*cont* #'(lambda ,parms ,@body))) ,expr))
```

Does the binding happens only when =values comes in later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro sets the continuation, `*cont*`, to be a lambda which takes all of your variables as arguments, and then evaluates the expression `expr`. The expression is expected to call the continuation with its final value, which can be done indirectly by calling the `=values` function, or directly with `funcall`. Unlike Scheme, where the continuation is implicitly called with the return value of any expression, you must explicitly write your code in continuation-passing style by calling `*cont*` or using `=values` instead of returning from any function.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this code, and I found that the continuation of the lambda is itself. I wouldn't be able to use this to port any continuation-based code I've written in Scheme.